# Need help understanding a math related Java method

Tags: java, function, javafx, methods, 2048

I'm currently working on remaking the game 2048 and I couldn't figure out how to rotate the tiles. Now I decided to take a look at GitHub to see how others solved this problem.

The git project I'm looking at: https://github.com/michaelzherdev/2048/blob/master/src/com/mzherdev/Game.java

The method I don't understand:

```
private Cell[] rotate(int angle) {
    Cell[] tiles = new Cell[4 * 4];
    int offsetX = 3;
    int offsetY = 3;
    if(angle == 90) {
        offsetY = 0;
    } else if(angle == 270) {
        offsetX = 0;
    }

    double rad = Math.toRadians(angle);
    int cos = (int) Math.cos(rad);
    int sin = (int) Math.sin(rad);
    for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
            int newX = (x*cos) - (y*sin) + offsetX;
            int newY = (x*sin) + (y*cos) + offsetY;
            tiles[(newX) + (newY) * 4] = cellAt(x, y);
        }
    }
    return tiles;
}
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out his thought process and why he is using radians.

Also can someone explain what he can mean with offsetX and y in other words? I'm not a native english speaker.

Thanks in advance!
Each answer is very appreciated!

Sincerely,
An aspiring dev

Comment: Because `Math.cos()` and `Math.sin()` use radians.

Comment: Take a look at [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). You need radians because `Math.sin()` and `Math.cos()` functions expect the angle to be in radians.

Comment: Unrelated to the rotations, you might want to check out [2048FX](https://github.com/brunoborges/fx2048), and if you want a step by step tutorial of the same, check out this [repository](https://github.com/jperedadnr/Game2048HOL). No rotations required...

Comment: Terrible title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 2):

He is using radians because the `Math.cos()` expects its argument to be in radians.

But really, using sin and cos to rotate a grid by increments of 90 degrees is overcomplicated, and quite brittle because trigonometric functions use floating point math, which is not guaranteed to return exact results, which might cause problems since `(int)` always rounds down, so `0.99999999999999` would become `0` or `-0.0000000000001` would become `-1`.

Fortunately, there is an easier way to rotate things in increments of 90 degrees. To figure out how, draw the usual coordinate grid (x-axis  extending to the right, and y-axis extending upwards) on a sheet of paper, and then grab this sheet and turn it 90 degrees clockwise. Now, the x-axis will point down, and the y-axis will point right. That is, the rotation caused the axes to exchange position, and one axis to extend in reverse direction. Put differently, we can rotate 90 degrees clockwise by exchanging x and y values, and flipping the sign of one:

```
int newx = oldy;
int newy = -oldx;
```

Now, your case is a bit more complicated because you are not rotating around the origin of the coordinate system but the midpoint of the tile. Compensating for this, the formula for rotating 90 degrees clockwise becomes:

```
int newx = oldy;
int newy = 3 - oldx;
```

and for rotating 90 degrees counter-clockwise:

```
int newx = 3 - oldy;
int newy = oldx;
```

So the easiest solution is to forget about all this sin and cos stuff and simply write

```
for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
        int newx;
        int newy;
        if (clockwise) {
            newx = oldy;
            newy = 3 - oldx;
        } else {
            newx = 3 - oldy;
            newy = oldx;
        }
        rotatedTile[newx][newy] = tile[x][y];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rotating objects is very simple in JavaFX - just call **setRotate(double angle)** like in the following example:

```
public void start(Stage ps) throws Exception {
    Button square = new Button();
    square.setOnAction(e -> {
        square.setRotate(square.getRotate() + 90);
    });

    VBox container = new VBox(square);

    ps.setScene(new Scene(container, 100, 100));
    ps.show();
}
```

**Math.cos** and **Math.sin** take as an argument and angle in radians.